# Google Chart QR Code - Data is greater than 2k + Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, qr-code

I am using Google Chart QR code , I have to send data more then 2k , I read document on

https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes

its says that

```
The data to encode. Data can be digits (0-9), alphanumeric characters, binary bytes data,
or Kanji. You cannot mix data types within a QR code. The data must be UTF-8 
URL-encoded.Note that URLs have a 2K maximum length, so if you want to encode more than 
 2K bytes (minus the other URL characters), you will have to send your data using POST.
```

Can any one have sample that how can I send data using POST for Google QR - Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used zxing library to solve my problem, I have downloaded Zxing Project and create DLL of it then reference that DLL into my project.

**Encoding**

```
        QRCodeWriter writer = new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter();
        string str = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000 ; i++)
            str += i;

        ByteMatrix byteMatrix = writer.encode(str, com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300);

        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        // Sample of DexExpress Control 
        ASPxBinaryImage1.ContentBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(byteMatrix.ToBitmap(), typeof(byte[]));

        byte[] b = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(byteMatrix.ToBitmap(), typeof(byte[]));
        string s = System.Convert.ToBase64String(b);
        //Sample of ASP.net Control
        image1.Attributes.Add("src", "data:image/png;base64," + s);
```

**Decoding**

```
        string strb64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(b);

        QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(strb64);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);

        LuminanceSource s = new RGBLuminanceSource(bmp, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        BinaryBitmap bb = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(s));


        Result result = reader.decode(bb);

        //Store result into string
        string resultText = result.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. You can pass chl more then 2K

```
<form action='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart' method='POST' runat="server">
<input type="hidden" name="cht" value="qr"  />
<input type="hidden" name="chl" value="This is testing"  />
<input type='hidden' name='chs' value='300x200' />
<input type="submit"  />
```